# knowing type of object in opcua on client side

Tags: opc, unified-automation-sdk

I am reading about information model in OPCUA. Below is text snippet.

OPC UA provides more powerful possibilities exposing the semantic of the provided data.
In addition to the data provided by Classic OPC, it allows exposing information
like that the measured temperature is provided by a specific type of sensor device
and allows to expose in a type hierarchy what kind of devices are supported.
Thereby, OPC UA clients can get the information that they are dealing with the
same kind of device at different places. By exposing much more semantics, OPC
UA servers allow clients to process highly sophisticated tasks by interpreting the
semantic of the provided data. That includes the automated integration of data
provided by an OPC UA server as well as engineering an OPC UA server from a
generic OPC UA client.

My question on above text snippet

1. How does client knows " measured temperature is provided by a specific type of sensor device" ? For example in below snapshot of UAExpert, I have furnace_9, how do we know that this of type of Furnance Controller type? I am not able to get that in UAExpert? Any clue or do we get only programmatically on client side?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the References View, you will notice that Furnace_9 has a **HasTypeDefinition reference** to FurnaceControllerType.